# or statement in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to use or statement in SQL but it's not producing the results I want.

Here I want to expand the code so they are either 0012 or 0005 with the rest of conditions being the same. Here is the codes I am trying to modify, and I just added second line but it doesn't get what I wanted.

```
 WHERE pr.code = '0005'
      OR pr.code = '0012'
      AND p.effdate > '2/8/2017'
      AND p.pnum not like 'R%'
      AND p.status like '6'
```

Comment: Most likely an issue with missing parenthesis. Try `(pr.code = '0005' OR pr.code = '0012')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add parenthesis:

```
WHERE (pr.code = '0005' OR pr.code = '0012')
  AND p.effdate > '2/8/2017'
  AND p.pnum not like 'R%'
  AND p.status like '6'
```

And in this case, as @MiloBellano mentioned in his answer, you can prevent such errors by using [`IN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator:

```
WHERE pr.code IN ('0005', '0012')
  AND p.effdate > '2/8/2017'
  AND p.pnum not like 'R%'
  AND p.status like '6'
```

Answer (score 1):

One word: Parenthesis

(extra words to make the post long enough)

Answer (score 1):

```
  WHERE (pr.code = '0005'
  OR pr.code = '0012')
  AND p.effdate > '2/8/2017'
  AND p.pnum not like 'R%'
  AND p.status like '6'
```

But I think that

```
  pr.code in ('0005','0012')
  AND p.effdate > '2/8/2017'
  AND p.pnum not like 'R%'
  AND p.status like '6'
```

looks nicer and probably faster

Answer (score 0):

```html
 WHERE (pr.code = '0005'
      OR pr.code = '0012')
      AND p.effdate > '2/8/2017'
      AND p.pnum not like 'R%'
      AND p.status like '6'
```